# is there any way to determine width and height of rgb values array?

Tags: c++, image-processing, rgb

I have RGB values array with raw size each time. I'm trying to determine which width/height it would be more suitable for it.

The idea is, I'm getting raw files and I want to display file data as BMP image (e.g Hex Workshop got that feature which called Data Visualizer)

Any suggestions?

Regards.

Comment: you can't know width and height from raw RGB without *some other* indication or information.  what else do you know about the array?  edit: unless your array length was 0 or 3 octets.

Comment: Are you asking about the width and height of the represented image?  As in "What should be the width and height of an image that has 20 pixels?"

Comment: @mark nothing but only 0 or 3 octets.. I don't want to know what width/height it will have, I also want to do some calculations which dimensions will be better for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the divisors of the pixel array size.

For instance, if your array contains 243 pixels, divisors are 1, 3, 9, 27, 81 and 243. It means that your image is either 1x243, 3x81, 9x27, 27x9, 81x3 or 243x1.

You can only guess which is the good one by analyzing image content, vertical or horizontal features, recurring patterns, common aspect ratio, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I'll think about it now.